# How to create punch holes with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, shadows

I use a `tcolorbox` as background for my pictures. The final color is not decided yet. Currently it's `green!5!white`. One of the pictures shall show a type of pattern like punch holes in a piece of paper. The background shall be visible through these holes. Moreover this piece of paper shall have a shadow and the shadow shall also be visible through these punch holes, but only at the top and left borders.
What I get so far:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        d0/.style={%
            font=\ttfamily},
        d1/.style={%
            minimum width  = 0.50 cm,
            minimum height = 0.75 cm,
            draw,
            fill=green!5!white,
            }
        ]

    \path [fill=white, draw, drop shadow] (-0.4,2.25) rectangle (2.9,8.5);
    \node at (1.25,9){bumpmap};
    \foreach \f [count=\x] in {%
        % percentage signs are necessary,
        % otherwise node style is not recognized correctly
        1,0,1,0,1,1,%
        0,0,0,0,1,0,%
        0,1,1,0,0,0,%
        0,1,0,0,0,1,%
        0,1,0,1,1,0,%
        0,0,0,0,1,1,%
        1,0,1,0,0,0,%
        0,0,1,0,0,1%    
        }{%
        \pgfmathMod{\x-1}{6};
        \edef\myx{\pgfmathresult};
        \pgfmathdiv{\x-1}{6};
        \edef\myy{\pgfmathresult};

        \node [d\f] at (\myx*0.5,8-\myy*0.75) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The punch holes are faked in my MWE. I could not manage the `evenoddrule` with so many holes and I miss also the shadow inside the green holes.
Ideas, hints or a solution are very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem, but complex. If the punching holes are really side by side, then there shouldn't be any lines (and shadows) between adjacent holes. Is the layout fixed, a one-time matrix, or does this have to generated flexibly for arbitrary combinations of punchholes?

Comment: The layout isn't fix in general, but for this one example yes. In the meanwhile I did it as you have mentioned with adjacent boxes. It shows artefacts, thin lines. What's about the one-time matrix? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in my comment, I like to post a workaround, which is not perfect and still shows very thin unwanted lines, but it shows at least what I wanted, the punch holes.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule]

        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)}]
            \node at (1.5,9.25){Pattern};
            \foreach \f [count=\x] in {%
                1,0,1,0,1,1,%
                0,0,0,0,1,0,%
                0,1,1,0,0,0,%
                0,1,0,0,0,1,%
                0,1,0,1,1,0,%
                0,0,0,0,1,1,%
                1,0,1,0,0,0,%
                0,0,1,0,0,1%    
                }{%
                \pgfmathMod{\x-1}{6};
                \edef\myx{\pgfmathresult};
                \pgfmathdiv{\x-1}{6};
                \edef\myy{\pgfmathresult};
                
                \ifthenelse {\f=0}
                    {\fill [drop shadow,fill=brown!20!white]
                        (\myx*0.5,8-\myy*0.8) rectangle ++(0.5,0.8);
                    }
                    {\fill [drop shadow,fill=brown!20!white]
                        (\myx*0.5,8-\myy*0.8) rectangle ++(0.5,0.8)
                        (\myx*0.5+0.1,8-\myy*0.8+0.1) rectangle ++(0.3,0.6);
                    }
            \path [draw] (0,2.4) rectangle (3,8.8);
            }
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add the option `draw=brown!20!white` to you `\fill` commands. On my screen, the thin lines vanish then.